# Set string type array key value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to create array in which key (Index) will be strId `(typeof strId is "string")` when I am doing so I am getting undefined value in list Below is code.

```
var myRoomIdList = [];
var strId = "43457";

myRoomIdList[strId] = strId;

console.log(myRoomIdList);
console.log(myRoomIdList.length);

console.log(myRoomIdList);
Output: Undefined, undefiend, ......43457 times

console.log(myRoomIdList.length);
Output: 43457
```

Please can anyone figure out why It's behaving in this manner. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use an object for this. Use `var myRoomIdList = {};`

Answer (score 3):

`[]` array is dedicated for the numeric index. You should use `{}` instead:

```
var myRoomIdList = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have numerical identifiers, use a map instead.

```
var map = {};

map["ID1"] = "xxx";
map["ID2"] = "yyy";
...
```